# Is it a bad practice to display a detailed information about a record in table

Tags: html, database-design, information-retrieval

I like to use tables as it will allow me to organize the data in a better manner. But now inside my application I am using tables to represents  different data which can give misleading meaning. for example I am displaying the list of all record in a table such as:-

[image]

Then I am also displaying the details of each record in a table where rows will have different context:-

[image]

For me the tables seems clear ,, but am I using tables in the right context?. Or usually table rows should represents the same type of objects (for example different organizations, not different properties about an organization )? ?

Comment: Is this question about HTML tables used in presentation, or Database tables used in data storage? You seem to be confusing the two.

Comment: It is about HTML tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. Most systems show information using tables. Look at any forum software, for instance. In terms of user-friendliness, you could emphasize your header rows on your top table. On your bottom table, you could emphasize the left row (a darker background or stronger font).

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion using tables in this scenery is ok. All data is exhibited in simple and clear way.